# Accidently Used migrate:refresh on a live enviroment

Tags: laravel

I accidentally used migrate:refresh and lost all my companies data. I'm panicking please help and tell me something can reverse this.

Comment: There is nothing in Laravel that can reverse this. Pray that your company makes nightly data-backups and restore one of those. Out of curiosity, did you also accidentally confirm the warning that Laravel throws when you run that command in production? Or was your `.env` value for `APP_ENV` not set to `production`?

Comment: I made this from scratch myself. I did not know about the production thing. So now this was all developed by me. Damn rookie mistake.

Comment: When you create a Laravel project, the default value for `APP_ENV` is `production`, and there's even a backup if you don't have it set, which is `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),` (in `config/app.php`). Sounds like you manually changed it to something else, but yeah; there's reasons it's like that. Amongst other things, having `APP_ENV=production` provides a lot of safety fallbacks for stuff like this; warnings, force confirms, etc etc. But regardless, `migrate:refresh`, `migrate:rollback` and `migrate:reset` are destructive commands; there's no built-in way to undo them...

Comment: Contact your hosting company and ask them if they have the latest backup of your DB

Comment: Luckily the project is only 2 month old, as well as most data transfers through to another source using an api. So its not game changing, but I am still panicking. I will try contacting my hosting company

Comment: Always have backup

Comment: If bin log is turned on in MySql config then there will be a log of every query that MySql has executed. This could be used to restore the database.

Answer (score 1):

Always have backups. I was lucky due to my circumstances and the products situation I won't lose my job.

But let this be a lesson to everybody, always have a backup in place.